# Not able to login to git-crypt because .gnupg/pubring.kbx file messed up

Tags: gnupg, git-crypt

I have messed up **.gnupg/pubring.kbx** file. I don't have any backup of the **.gnupg** folder. But still, I have my GPG Public and Private keys. I am unable to unlock git-crypt. When I list the **.gnupg** folder in my mac, lt lists these files:

```
S.gpg-agent  S.gpg-agent.extra  openpgp-revocs.d  pubring.kbx
trustdb.gpg  S.gpg-agent.browser  S.gpg-agent.ssh
private-keys-v1.d  pubring.kbx~
```

Is there any way to recover back that file so that I can do *git-crypt unlock*? OR Is there any way to do *git-crypt unlock* without that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you have your public and private key in hand. Here are the steps you will need to follow:

1. Goto your gnugp dir

   ```
   cd ~/.gnupg
   ```
2. Deleting the corrupted pubring.kbx

   ```
   rm pubring.kbx
   ```
3. Copy pubring.kbx~ as pubring.kbx. This will give you an empty pubring which will not have any secret keys. Its like a fresh start.

   ```
   cp pubring.kbx~ pubring.kbx
   ```
4. Import your public key

   ```
   gpg --import <your-public-key-file.asc>
   ```

Good luck!